# MySQL: Unknown column ' ' in 'field list' error

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working with MySQL for a while now and I think i'm getting the hang of it! Until now, I tried my hands on a very simple form and it didn't work at all! I have created this database called: 'users' and I created a table called 'user' inside that database. Every time I ran the script, I got an Unknown column error. Here is the code: (sign_in.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign In</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<h2>Complete the form below:</h2>
Username <input type="text" name="user-name" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the processing file (test.php):

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'mac');
mysql_select_db('users', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));   
$result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name) VALUES (NULL, ' . $_POST['user-name'] . ')', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
echo 'Completed!';
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It still doesn't work! I used these syntaxes all months long and they work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your **test.php** with the following code. it works.

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mac");
mysql_select_db("users", $db);
$username = $_POST['user-name'];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name) VALUES ('', '$username')", $db)
echo 'Completed!';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this:

```
'INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name) VALUES (NULL, ' . $_POST['user-name'] . ')'
```

but according to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755944/error-unknown-column-in-field-list-mysql-error) it should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_POST['user-name'] . "')"
```

the user-name value is not enclosed in single quotes in your code.